# Extracting Data between tags using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

im writing a program to extract data between paragraph tags

```
    <h2>User Reviews</h2>
    <div class="user-comments">
                <div class="tinystarbar" title="2/10">
                    <div style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            <span itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">  
                <strong itemprop="name">Terrible movie</strong>
                <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="2">
                    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10">
                </span>
                <div class="comment-meta">
                    22 December 2013 | by <a href="/user/ur49033470/?ref_=tt_urv"><span itemprop="author">sarconus</span></a>
                    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-12-22">
                    – <a href="/user/ur49033470/comments?ref_=tt_urv">See all my reviews</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p itemprop="reviewBody">This was one of the worst movies I have watched in quite sometime.The fist movie was fantastic and I still quote it to this day...<br><br>Sadly they played the dumb card the entire movie. Only funny parts were raciest. They couldn't make up their mind on what they wanted to do with this movie and brought in elements from the first that shouldn't have been touched.<br><br>Sorry this was a waste of time and money. The first movie will forever live in glory but this one will pass away.<br><br>If you loved the fist movie I would recommend waiting for DVD or just pass this one.</p>
                </div>
            </span>
            <hr>
            <div class="yn" id="ynd_2926802">
                37 of 66 people found this review helpful.&nbsp;
                Was this review helpful to you?
                <button class="btn small" value="Yes" name="ynb_2926802_yes" onclick="CS.TMD.user_review_vote(2926802, 'tt1229340', 'yes');">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn small" value="No" name="ynb_2926802_no" onclick="CS.TMD.user_review_vote(2926802, 'tt1229340', 'no');">No</button>
            </div>
        <div class="see-more">

            <a href="/title/tt1229340/reviews-enter?ref_=tt_urv" rel="login" class="cboxElement">Review this title</a>
            <span>|</span>
                <a href="/title/tt1229340/reviews?ref_=tt_urv">See all 212 user reviews</a>&nbsp;»
        </div>
    </div>
```

executing the javascript on the above html im getting [object list] how can i get the data in a variable im using awesomium plugin as webbrowser

document.getElementsByTagName("p"); is used for extracting

Answer (score 0):

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
   var p = paragraphs[i];       // this is the DOM element 
   var text = p.innerText;      // this is the text inside the <p></p> tags
   console.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dojo you can do like this

```
function stripTags(str) { 
    return domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: str }).textContent; 
}
```

you can do similar stuff with other framework if they offer.